# Migrate TFS 2018 Update 3 to Azure DevOps Services

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2018

I'm trying to migrate from TFS 2018 version 16.131.28106.2 (Tfs2018.Update3) to Azure DevOps using migration tool in this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274

DataMigrationTool_AzureDevOps2019.0.1_17.144.9617800

but when i try to run the below command I'm getting below error

Command:

C:\TFSMigrator\DataMigrationTool>Migrator validate /collection:http://192.168.1.
 19:8080/tfs/ProductsEngine

Error:

The data migration tool was unable to find an installation path for the Azure De
 vOps Server Application Tier. Either Azure DevOps Server is not installed, you a
 re using a version of the data migration tool that isn't supported for your vers
 ion of Azure DevOps Server, or you are using a version of Azure DevOps Server th
 at is not supported for import.

See https://aka.ms/AzureDevOpsImportSupportedVersions to check that your version
  of Azure DevOps Server is supported for import.
 See https://aka.ms/AzureDevOpsImport to download the Migrator version that works
  with your Azure DevOps Server version.
 See https://aka.ms/AzureDevOpsImportValidate for details on running Migrator on
 your collection.

please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation that the error message provided.

> The data migration tool for Azure DevOps supports the two latest releases of Azure DevOps Server at a given time. Releases include updates and major releases. Currently the following versions of Azure DevOps Server are supported for import:
>
> - **Azure DevOps Server 2019**
> - **Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1**

You will note that TFS 2018 is **not a supported version**. You will have to upgrade first.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for getting back to me quickly, could you please share with me any guide to how to upgrade from TFS 2018 Update 3 to Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1?

Comment: @AliIsmailShhadeh The best place to start is the upgrade documentation provided by Microsoft.